# How to utilize nodes

Tags: java, stack, queue, nodes

I'm working on a homework assignment but i feel like i am completely lost. The point of this homework assignment is to use nodes to cycle through stacks and queues, but i dont think i am doint it right. No where in my current code do i have anything going to the node class and im sure i should have something going there. I'm just getting started working on main, testing the functions and stuff.

Car class

```
public class Car {
    String plate;
    char code;

    public Car(String plate, char code){
    }
    public String getPlate(){
        return plate;
    }
    public void setPlate(String inPlate){
        plate = inPlate;
    }
}
```

node class

```
public class Node {
    Node next;
    Car name;

    public Node(Node x, Car y){
        next = x;
        name = y;
    }
}
```

Lstack class

```
public class Lstack {
    int size;
    int numUsed = 0;
    Car[] stack;
    public Lstack(){
        stack = new Car[size];
    }
    public void push(Car x){
        stack[numUsed] = x;
        numUsed++;
    }
    public Car pop(){
        Car temp;
        numUsed--;
        temp = stack[numUsed];
        return temp;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        if(numUsed==0){
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    public int size(){
        return numUsed;
    }
    public void display(){
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        System.out.print("TOP | ");
        for(int i = 0; i < numUsed; i++){
            System.out.print(stack[i].plate +" | ");
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
    }

}
```

Lqueue class

```
public class Lqueue {
    int size;
    int numUsed = 0;
    Car[] queue;
    public Lqueue(){
        queue = new Car[size];
    }
    public void insert(Car x){
        int index = numUsed;
        for(int i = numUsed; i >= 0; i--){
            queue[index + 1] = queue[index];
            index--;
        }
        queue[0] = x;
    }
    public Car remove(){
        Car temp;
        temp = queue[numUsed];
        queue[numUsed] = null;
        numUsed--;
        return temp;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        if(numUsed==0){
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    public int size(){
        return numUsed;
    }
    public void display(){
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        System.out.print("Front | ");
        for(int i = numUsed; i >= 0; i--){
            System.out.print(queue[i].plate +" | ");
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `size` field in `Lstack` is not initialized. It will default to 0. Pass an argument to your constructor or set a default value different than 0 (hopefully).

Answer (score 1):

**google: "linked list implementation"**

You should have the Nodes in your data structures.

You should not be using arrays.

Comment: can you show me what i might do to fix it? This whole node thing is new to me.

Comment: @user1801067 google comes back with lots of tutorials, try: http://codingfreak.blogspot.com/2009/08/implementation-of-singly-linked-list-in.html

Comment: @user1801067 stacks and queues will be very similar to the linked list.

Comment: I looked at the link, and have half a clue what is going on. I dont know how to make the node.next be in my code and work effectively. I mean is what i have anywhere close?

Comment: @user1801067 vaguely, you will want to replace your usage of array with a linked list. The linked list will use the nodes.

Comment: @user1801067 another example, this time of a Queue http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/util/QueueImplement.shtml

Comment: i understand what a linked list does, im just having a hard time implementing it.

Comment: @user1801067 check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557192/linked-list-implementation-java for a start.

Answer (score 1):

Start by changing `Car[]` to `Node[].` in the `Lqueue` class.

Then change `Node[]` to `Node` and instead of using an array us the node.next variable to traverse the list.

[Here is a wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) on linked lists.  Substitute the 12, 99, and 37 in the example with different Cars...

Comment: i really dont understand this. can you make an example for me please?